# Getting the path of an image from an IO.Stream object

Tags: c#, image, xaml, stream, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 app, and I need to allow users to use images from their camera roll in the app. I can get the image to display just fine by making a `BitmapImage` from the chosen photo of a `PhotoChooserTask`, however when the user leaves the app I have no idea how to save the URI of the image to the app.

Maybe I'm just blind and can't find the property in the documentation, but is there anywhere I can find the URI of the image so it can be loaded later into an `Image` control?

Comment: If you're getting a `PhotoResult` from the `PhotoChooserTask`, it should expose a `FileName` property you can use to create the URI

Comment: Awesome. Could you make this a proper answer so I can accept it, maybe adding the relevant path to the user's camera roll folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PhotoResult` returned by the `PhotoChooserTask` exposes the file name through the `OriginalFileName` property.

The `OriginalFileName` is simply a string, which you can use to construct a `URI`.  If, as you mentioned, you need to get path information, you can use `System.IO.Path` e.g.

```
string filename = YourPhotoResult.OriginalFileName;
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) // Gets the directory the file is located in
```

Here's an MSDN link to the PhotoResult class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult(v=vs.105).aspx